# How can I include a div with Javascript? Using MANDRILL & Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We're trying to have the modal-body div below included in the email sent by Mandrill.  Or set it up as a variable. Does anyone know how we could do this in a simple manner using the same setup we have now for the other included variables in the email? Thanks so much!

```
eventClick: function(event) {
  console.log(event)
    // alert(event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'))
  var start = event.start.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
    end = event.end.format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
    html = '<p>Starts: ' + start + '<p>';
  html += '<p>Ends: ' + end + '<p>';
  var modal = $("#modal");
  modal.find(".modal-title").html(event.title);
  modal.find('.modal-body').html(html)
  modal.modal();
    }
});
});
});//]]> 


jQuery(function($)  
{
$("#contact_form").submit(function()
{

    var email = $("#email").val(); // get email field value
    var name = $("#name").val(); // get name field value
    var msg = $("#msg").val(); // get message field value
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json",
        data: {
            'key': 'API',
            'message': {
                'from_email': "email@email.com",
                'from_name': "name",
                'headers': {
                    'Reply-To': "email@email.com"
                },
                'subject': 'Confirmation -  Sign Up',
  RIGHT HERE--->'text':   , 
                'to': [
                {
                    'email': email,
                    'name': name,
                    'type': 'to'
                }]

            }
        }
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        alert('You have been signed up. Thank you!'); // show success message
        $("#name").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        $("#email").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
        $("#msg").val(''); // reset field after successful submission
    })
```

HTML: